# kohana with postgres, can't connect

Tags: kohana

I'm playing with Kohana Framework, and I'm stucked at the very first step:

I want to use it with PostgreSQL, but I'm getting an error in Kohana:

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Database_Pgsql' not found
MODPATH/database/classes/kohana/database.php [ 78 ]
73 
74          // Set the driver class name
75          $driver = 'Database_'.ucfirst($config['type']);
76 
77          // Create the database connection instance
78          new $driver($name, $config);
79      }
80 
81      return Database::$instances[$name];
82  }
83 
{PHP internal call} » Kohana_Core::shutdown_handler()
```

This is my database.php file

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct access allowed.');

return array
(
'default' => array
(
    'type'       => 'pgsql',
    'connection' => array(
        'dsn'        => 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=globalgest',
        'hostname'   => 'localhost',
        'database'   => 'globalgest',
        'username'   => 'postgres',
        'password'   => 'xxxxxxx',
        'persistent' => FALSE,
    ),
    'table_prefix' => '',
    'charset'      => 'utf8',
    'caching'      => FALSE,
    'profiling'    => TRUE,
),
);
```

In the php ini I can see the postgrsql drivers installed correctly:

```
pgsql

PostgreSQL Support  enabled
PostgreSQL(libpq) Version   9.0.5
Multibyte character support enabled
SSL support enabled
Active Persistent Links 0
Active Links    0
```

What else I'm missing ?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or use the native postgress driver: https://github.com/cbandy/kohana-postgresql

Comment: native for who? Wich driver is using Kohana for postgresql by default ?

Comment: Why the default pg driver doesn't work ? This native driver is better ? Where I can find more info ? In the git page there's nothing about it ... thanks

Comment: "native" meaning the driver would use the native php postgres functions, not pdo. There is no "default" pg driver, kohana only officially supports and maintains mysql and pdo.

Answer (score 2):

Database 'type' in your config shouldn't be 'pgsql' but 'pdo' instead.

Comment: I pointed this out because you specified the DSN in your config :) Now I see @zombor already replied so ... GL

Comment: ok, thanks for clarification! I used the DSN because it wasn't working without it :-)